# check old php scripts for upgradeing/migrating to newer php version

Tags: php, migration, upgrade

I've many PHP-Scripts based on older PHP Versions. I'm currently using PHP 5.3 and want to upgrade to a newer Version, but I don't know which is compatible with the functions I'm using. Is there a Framework or any other tool to check the Scripts with? I want to upgrade/migrate to PHP 7.2 and I know that some functions (like mysql) are removed. 
I don't remember every function I used in those hundreds of Scripts and don't really want to search line for line for deprecated and removed functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [Phan](https://github.com/phan/phan). It runs under PHP and can statically analyze your scripts for compatibility with newer PHP versions.

If you call it using

```
phan --directory <directory_with_scripts> --target-php-version 7.2
```

It'll tell you what will fly and what will not!

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm reading the doc and it says Phan depends on PHP version 7 or greater... I'm using PHP Version 5.6 and my scripts are even older Versions

Comment: Install php 7 alongside 5.6 or on a different server. It just needs php 7 to run its code but it can certainly check old code against 7.2